# How to use a for loop in awk for its current line with regex format

Tags: bash, awk

This is my text file I need to process:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| ID                                   | Name             | Status  | Task State | Power State | Networks                                                               | Image Name | Image ID                             | Plan Name      | Plan ID                              | Server Zone       | Host                     | Properties           |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| 7ddd34d7-f081-4228-8023-9f3e2c5c686c | some_hostname    | ACTIVE  | None       | Running     | External_Network=2.2.2.2; Internal_Network=10.10.10.3                  | Ubuntu20   | 584f8dd7-2554-4215-8fc2-7c16ade9d5d6 | Plan A100C124  | 9511d8a1-dc84-4c6b-addc-328751c73d2f | Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com | Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com        | some test properties |
| dd39f9c4-7043-431d-aa97-a3a6b60286d7 | another hostname | ACTIVE  | None       | Running     | External_Network=3.3.3.3                                               | Ubuntu20   | 584f8dd7-2554-4215-8fc2-7c16ade9d5d6 | Plan A200G84   | 9511d8a1-dc84-4c6b-addc-328751c73d2f | Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com | Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com        |                      |
| 005b5329-d506-4482-8d2c-54e429e90b56 | third server     | ACTIVE  | None       | Running     | External_Network=4.4.4.4; Internal_Network=10.10.10.106, 10.10.11.106  | Centos7    | 33b0b27d-daa6-44a4-ac04-96bbbf5f78f5 | Dlan A50C22    | b6a93f35-26e6-416b-9d46-bef6651b3011 | Z1DG2.my-fqdn.com | old-hostname.my-fqdn.com | admin notes          |
| 060fdefa-259b-4256-8781-98b535ec11c3 | last one         | ACTIVE  | None       | Running     | External_Network=5.5.5.5                                               | Debian 12  | b98de22d-03a9-4417-ac23-9026344ad74d | Plan A40G12    | 824a373c-01c4-439c-9576-f862a74069e5 | Z1DG2.my-fqdn.com | old-hostname.my-fqdn.com |                      |
| be4f5a16-8817-489e-b250-a10e72ab3187 | 1.1.1.1          | PAUSED  | None       | Paused      | External_Network=1.1.1.1                                               | RedHat 8   | 69289e81-2dd6-4dbf-af73-8187f8277fab | Vlan A250C2418 | 801de143-d172-4b38-b5bb-969dd1eb2289 | Z1SG3.my-fqdn.com | Z1SG3.my-fqdn.com        |                      |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

This is the text I want to process.

I want to check if `plan name` and `server zone` match each other in each line.

The results of each line (only second part of plan name matters):

1. Plan `A100C124` is in server zone `Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com`. Since the letter `C` does not match `DG` in server zone name, so the IP `2.2.2.2` is created in the wrong server.
2. Plan `A200G84` is in server zone `Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com`. Since the letter `G` does match `DG` in server zone name, so the IP `3.3.3.3` is created in the correct server.
3. Plan `A50C22` is in server zone `Z1DG2.my-fqdn.com`. Since the letter `C` does not match `DG` in server zone name, so the IP `4.4.4.4` is created in the wrong server.
4. Plan `A40G12` is in server zone `Z1DG2.my-fqdn.com`. Since the letter `G` does match `DG` in server zone name, so the IP `5.5.5.5` is created in the correct server.
5. Plan `A250C2418` is in server zone `Z1SG3.my-fqdn.com`. Since the letter `G` does not match `SG` in server zone name, so the IP `1.1.1.1` is created in the wrong server.

**The logic**

1. Plan names are: letter `A` (it's fixed) + digits from `1` to `3` characters (the regex format [0-9]{1,3}) + either letters `C` or `G` (based on the plan name) + digits from `1` to `9` characters (the regex format [0-9]{1,9}) ==> `A[0-9]{1,3}[CG][0-9]{1,9}`
2. Server names are: the letter `Z` (it's fixed) + digits from `1` to `2` characters (the regex format [0-9]{1,2}) + either letters `S` or `G` (based on server specs to own which letter) + digits from `1` to `3` characters (the regex format [0-9]{1,3}) + the name `.my-fqdn.com` ==> `Z[0-9]{1,2}[DS][CG][0-9]{1,3}\.my-fqdn.com`

**Expected output**

```
wrong server ==> ip 2.2.2.2, plan A100C124, server Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com
wrong server ==> ip 4.4.4.4, plan A50C22, server Z1DG2.my-fqdn.com
wrong server ==> ip 1.1.1.1, plan A250C2418, server Z1SG3.my-fqdn.com
```

Since now, I learned from my other questions and the answers how to do a for loop. But this is a for loop but should check only its current line. I mean the line 1 should be compared with line 1. But it should not check line 1 with line 2 or other lines.

I have no attempts since now unfortunately (I'm so sad for this after lots of asking).

**Update 1**

The plan names are not always `Plan`, they're sometimes `Vlan`, `Plan` or like this.

Comment: A lot of inconsistencies in your description, like *letter C does not match DC*, *...  letter G does not match SG*, ... Server name has *... [0-9]{1,2}) + either letters S or G* - while it has `<digits>+[DS]G`. Put corrections in your description

Comment: Is your input text really in a table in markdown format?

Comment: @Fravadona yes, the output is in table format.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping over lines in awk is implicit. Here's a straightforward solution with GNU Awk using `match` with the regexes you provided, with the parts to be extracted in grouping parentheses to reference them in the comparison and printout:

```bash
awk -F\| 'NF>3 {
  match($7, /External_Network=([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/, ip);
  match($10, /A[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9}/, plan);
  match($12, /Z[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\.my-fqdn.com/, server);
  if (plan[1] != server[1])
    print "wrong server ==> ip", ip[1] ",", "plan", plan[0] ",", "server", server[0]
}'
```

```
wrong server ==> ip 2.2.2.2, plan A100C124, server Z1DG3.my-fqdn.com
wrong server ==> ip 4.4.4.4, plan A50C22, server Z1DG2.my-fqdn.com
wrong server ==> ip 1.1.1.1, plan A250C2418, server Z1SG3.my-fqdn.com
```

Comment: Thanks, I only had an issue, that the IP regex was one digit only, that I modified for myself to the digits.